# Spring Security - Differentiate between wrong username/password combination and unauthorised users

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

In a Spring Boot + Spring Security application I have written my own `AuthenticationProvider`. It does authentication against another server, which holds information about usernames and their passwords.

So far, everything works fine - through the use of `failureUrl(String)`on the `formLogin()`in the Security-Configuration I can tell people that they have used invalid username/password combinations. Spring will also automatically redirect unauthorised requests to the login-Form.

However, there is the possibility that a user provides a valid username/password combination, but is simply not allowed to use the application anyway. Such user should, of course, not receive the same feedback of "wrong username/password", as that would be confusing to him. Is there any way in my `AuthenticationProvider`or maybe the Security-Configuration that I can somehow implement a case differentiation between these two? So far I can't see any way, returning null in the `AuthenticationProvider` makes Spring assume it's a "failure" and thus just redirects to the path specified in `failureUrl(String)`.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you differentiate between authentication and authorization. A user with valid credentials should always be authenticated. Access might still be denied due to missing authorization.

So how about granting the role "USER" for all users really allowed to use your app and configuring your app to require this role for specific requests like so:

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()                   
        .antMatchers("/api/**").hasRole("USER")                                                            
        .anyRequest().authenticated()                                                               
        .and()
        // ...
        .httpBasic();   
}
```

Comment: Is that how it would usually be done? I think it could work very well - although I would have to make sure that the user can also logout again. I guess I would combine your answer with jzheaux's answer, so that I can use an AccessDeniedHandler to display some information about why the user cannot enter the site.

Comment: Differentiate between Authentication and Authorization? Definitely. And indeed using the AccessDeniedHandler would be the way to go. If you plan to have different access rights within your application anyway, I would give it a try. You'll find Spring automatically structuring your code in a clean way without mixing responsibilities. Have a look at _AccessDecisionVoter_ and _AccessDecisionManager_.

Answer (score 1):

Spring Security supports this scenario using two different interfaces.

### `AuthenticationFailureHandler`

Spring Security uses this API to determine how to deal with authentication failure (e.g. bad creds). It's quite common to want to redirect back to the login page, so this is what happens by default. However, you can customize it with

```
http
    .formLogin()
        .failureUrl(myUrl)
```

or

```
http
    .formLogin()
        .failureHandler(myFailureHandler)
```

for more sophisticated needs.

### [`AccessDeniedHandler`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#access-denied-handler)

Say that the user is logged in, though, but they are requesting a protected resource to which they do not have access.

By default, Spring Security returns a 403, but it can be configured to be an access denial page, too:

```
http
    .exceptionHandling()
        .accessDeniedPage(myAccessDeniedPage)
```

or

```
http
    .exceptionHandling()
        .accessDeniedHandler(myAccessDeniedHandler)
```

for more sophisticated needs.

Your `AuthenticationProvider` should just focus on authenticating the user -- you can throw an `AuthenticationException` to indicate failure. The `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` will take care of picking up the failure url and the `ExceptionTranslationFilter` will pick up the access denied page.

Comment: Ah, very interesting - I will have to look into the AuthenticationFailureHandler tomorrow. I will have to see how I can pass the information of which cases has occured from my custom AuthenticationProdiver to my custom AuthenticationFailureHandler - I took a quick peek and it looks like it works via Exceptions that are thrown in the AuthenticationProvider. I will look more closely tomorrow and report back, thanks for your input so far!

Answer (score 0):

You can make a custom class for the case that the user is unauthorized:

```java
public class UnauthorizedException extends AuthenticationException {

    public UnauthorizedException(String msg) {
        super(msg);
    }

}
```

The important is to extend Spring Security's `AuthenticationException` if you use it from your `AuthenticationProvider` implementation. Simply use it like:

```
throw new UnauthorizedException("Unauthorized to use this application.");
```

You may want to localize the message.

Such exception will be put in the session in an attribute named `SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION`. If you for example use Thymeleaf you can print the message like this:

```html
<p data-th-if="${param.error != null and session.SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION != null}"
   data-th-text="${session.SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION.message}">
</p>
```

Answer (score -2):

Hope this will help you

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/login")
public String getLoginPage(@RequestParam(name = "error", required = false) String error, Model model,
        @RequestParam(name = "logout", required = false) String logout) {
    if (error != null) {
        model.addAttribute("message", "Invalid Username or Password");
    }
    if (logout != null) {
        model.addAttribute("logout", "You have Successfully Logged Out");
    }

    return "login";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/logout-user")
public String logout(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    // fetch the authentication object
    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    if (auth != null) {
        // logout and clear out the session and remove the authentication from the
        // security context
        new SecurityContextLogoutHandler().logout(request, response, auth);
    }
    return "redirect:/login?logout";
}
```

Spring-security configuration

```
<http>

    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="permitAll" />
    <!-- navigate to login url -->
    <form-login login-page="/login" username-parameter="username"
        password-parameter="password" />
    <!-- access forbidden for unauthorized user -->
    <access-denied-handler error-page="/access-denied" />
    <csrf />
</http>
```

Comment: Sadly your answer does not really answer the question - you have just shown how basic Authorization without the special use case that I am trying to implement works.